# аналог Embedded(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) в JPA2.1

Tags: java, jpa, embedded, lazyloading

У меня есть сущность Car, в соответствующей таблице в базе около 250 колонок. Но в 95% случаев про работе с Car достаточно 5 колонок. Мне нужно сделать чтобы дополнение сведенья об Car подтягивались по мере надобности, но Lazy с embedded-объектом не работает. В какую сторону копать чтобы сделать что-то подобное при помощи JPA2.1?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "licence_plate",nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Embedded(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private CarSetting carSetting;
}

@Embeddable
public class CarSetting extends Car implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "color")
    private String color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Копать в сторону отдельной таблицы для дополнительных сведений. Тем более если они не так уж и нужны.
Другой вариант - создать not-mapped класс урезанной версии Car-а, извлекать из базы его (оператор NEW в JPQL, например). А когда нужно - переходить к настоящему Car-у. Но это уже не будет lazy - придётся самому поработать.